# Ruby keyword as named hash parameter

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

Is it possible to access the hash holding keyword arguments using the new ruby 2.0 syntax?

```
class List::Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next
  def initialize data: nil, next: nil
    self.data = data
    self.next = next # ERROR! 
  end
end
```

Old syntax works fine:

```
class List::Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next
  def initialize options = { data: nil, next: nil }
    self.data = options[:data]
    self.next = options[:next] 
  end
end
```

----- EDIT -----

I realize `next` is a reserved word but I'm guessing keyword attributes are stored internally in a hash and I'm wondering whether it's possible to access it, e.g. via `self.args`, `self.parameters`, `self.options`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
class List::Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next
  def initialize data: nil, _next: nil
    self.data = data
    self.next = _next
  end
end
```

`next` is Ruby reserved word. Use names which are not Ruby's reserved keyword.

EDIT: Yes, possible, but not a good idea.

```
class List::Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next
  def initialize data: nil, next: nil
    self.data = data
    self.next = binding.local_variable_get(:next)
  end
end
p List::Node.new.next # nil
```

Look [`local_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) .

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I'd never put this code on production but I'm playing around with ruby trying to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

Just like `*args` collects all the positional parameters you *didn't* mention in the argument list, `**kwargs` collects all the keyword arguments you *didn't* mention in the argument list. As far as I know, there is no non-hacky way to access a positional parameter both from a declared parameter and a splat at the same time, and the same goes for keyword arguments.

```
def foo(pos1, pos2, *args, reqkw:, optkw: nil, **kwargs)
  puts [pos1, pos2, reqkw, optkw, args, kwargs].inspect
end
foo(1, 2, 8, reqkw: 3, optkw: 4, extkw: 9)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, [8], {:extkw=>9}]
```

I.e. you can access `1`, `2` only as positional arguments, and `8` only from the splat; in the same way, you can access `3` and `4` only from the keyword arguments, and `9` only from the doublesplat.

(Arup Rakshit already gives the hacky way to access parameters by symbol - but note that this accesses all local variables, not only parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `next` a Ruby keyword. Choose another name and it should be fine.